# Regular expression to find all math operations

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an expression like this:

```
5*3 + 2 +7 -sqrt(32312.323)
```

And i want to find all of the math operation in that expression. I've tried:

```
[A-Za-z\*\+\-\/]
```

Because of the "-" is next to the "sqrt" operation so it got combined as "-sqrt", i want them to be separated in this case ? How can i fix this ?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: What's your expected output? Do you want all digits and operators to be separated, or what?

Comment: Try `[*+\/-]+|[A-Za-z]+` but I'm not certain about the performance.

Comment: What language/library/tool are you using? What's your code (i.e. how are you using this regex)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance my expected ouput is "-" and sqrt got separated, the same for any other same case

Comment: @revo It's worked. Thanks, but what is the time complexity of that ?

Comment: @melpomene I'm just started to use Regex on https://regexr.com/, i'm planning to implement it in Python soon

Comment: Why do you think `-sqrt` gets combined? [Your regex](https://regexr.com/3tgb6) matches `-`, `s`, `q`, `r`, `t` separately.

Comment: @melpomene ohhh, sorry i miss spot that :((

Comment: I wasn't really uncertain about the performance if you take look at the user's name who commented just before me. The performance is totally fine.

Comment: @revo: Ohhhh. hehe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[*+\/-]+|[A-Za-z]+
```

This will works. According to @CertainPerformance The performance of that should be fine. The problem is always when several branches of alternation start with matching the same content (like a*|aa*, for example). There is no possibility your two branches will ever both match on the same character, so that is as good as regex gets.

Also, thanks for your answer @revo.

Comment: `a*|aa*` is equivalent to `a*`. There's no performance problem there.

Comment: @melpomene "`a*|aa*` is equivalent to `a*`" - Not inside larger regexp. `/^a*$/` will be fine, `/^(a*)*$/` will be less fine, `/^(a*|aa*)*$/` will very quickly exhibit catastrophic backtracking when applied to e.g. `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaX"`.

Comment: @Amadan The problem with `(a*|aa*)*` is the same problem as with `(a*)*`: Nested overlapping loops, not `|`.